# Processing Multimedia Content

Tags: 2013-sp1, templating

I have got a requirement where business people would be uploading the xml files (not more than 25 file) as multimedia components and we need to expose them as JSON. I started on the POC and after a bit of trial and error I am able to achieve it as below.

Is this approach achievable in Prod environment? As i am doubtful that It might cause an issue (memory leaks, etc) in an environment where the WCM is used heavily and performance is the highest priority. I am getting this thought seeing memory stream and xml files of sizes around 2MB.

I am confused in deciding the approach even though the below is working because I am fairly new to these kind of stream objects.

```
 public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
    {

    try
    {
        Initialize(engine, package);

        Item componentItem = Package.GetByType(ContentType.Component);
        Component component = engine.GetObject(componentItem) as Component;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryContent binary = component.BinaryContent;
                binary.WriteToStream(memoryStream);                  
                xmlDoc.Load(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Close();
            }

            string jsonoutput = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(GetXmlValues(XElement.Parse(doc.OuterXml)));

            package.PushItem(Package.OutputName, Package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, jsonoutput));


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Exception raised:" + ex.Message);
    }
}

private Dictionary<string, object> GetXmlValues(XElement xml)
{
    var attr = xml.Attributes().ToDictionary(d => d.Name.LocalName, d => (object)d.Value);
    if (xml.HasElements) attr.Add("_value", xml.Elements().Select(e => GetXmlValues(e)));
    else if (!xml.IsEmpty) attr.Add("_value", xml.Value);

    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { xml.Name.LocalName, attr } };
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *why* you want to store XML data as a Multimedia Component instead of as a "regular" Component?

Comment: We dont want the business users to mess up the xml while copy pasting into a regular component.

Comment: You could use WebDAV to let the Business Users upload complete XML files into regular XML components ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you need is JSON, rather than processing this at publish time, might it not be easier (and better for performance) to process it at creation time already?

For starters I would never suggest to use a Multimedia Component for this, since it is not a binary, but a text file you are dealing with. If you wanted to store the XML, you should simply create a Schema for it and store it as a regular Component. However since what you need is JSON, I would suggest to create an event handler which on creation of the Component transforms the XML into JSON and stores it in a text field of the Component.

As mentioned my Rick already, to convert the XML into JSON, you can best use Json.NET, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json#814027

Comment: This would be a pain as while copying the xml, business users might mess up the xml and hence this approach isn't accepted. But personally, I like this approach.

Comment: If the content must remain valid XML, definitely don't choose for Multimedia Components and create a Schema for it and store it as a normal Component.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the question why you would want to store XML data in a BLOB instead of in a regular/structured/XML Component, I have the following comments on your code:

- You are first loading the binary data into an in-memory buffer (`MemoryStream`), then parse it into an XML DOM (`XmlDocument`), then serialize it to an XML string (`doc.OuterXml`), then parse it into another kind of XML DOM (`XElement.Parse`) and finally transform it into a Dictionary which is serialized to a JSON string. Obviously, this is not very efficient; you only need one kind of XML DOM --  get rid of the LINQ to XML and query the `XmlDocument` directly or get the XML string directly from the `MemoryStream` using a `StreamReader`.
- `JavaScriptSerializer` is one of the least efficient JSON serializers. JSON.NET is one of the most efficient ones (but a third party component, which you would have to ILMerge in your .NET Assembly TBB). `DataContractJsonSerializer` is inbetween, but conveniently part of the .NET Framework. See: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm

Comment: Json.net seems to be a good option and thanks for pointing out the performance pitfalls.